# How to find the height of Firefox's Add-on Bar using Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, height, toolbar

Firefox's Addon toolbar can have more than one dimensions eg depending on whether text is displayed along with icons etc. So is it possible to find the exact height using javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do this using JavaScript, as it is part of the browser chrome.